# How can I remove the square slider pre loading animation and how do I include my nav bar logo to load at the same time as the slider?

Tags: html, css

1) Firstly, how do I remove the square slider pre loading animation. As you can see in the link below the square animation box appears before the slider loads. How can I get rid of that?

2) Secondly, how do I include my nav bar logo to load at the same time as the slider? As you can see the navigation bar logo is one the page the second it opens then a couple seconds later everything else loads. Example is in the link.

[streamable.com/houbg](https://streamable.com/houbg)

[Website code, I think the index.html page is the issue with these two problems I'm trying to fix.](https://github.com/liamdocherty/car_detailing)

Kind Regards,
Liam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I can't post comments yet so I'll put this up as an answer.

Your menu items are white, so on a white background it would seem they aren't there. I highly recommend you change the site's background colour or at least the container/section behind the slider to a dark/grey colour, then you would see what's going on better. But also do this so in the event the slider or background image fails to load, users can still see the site menu!

So the only thing that's still loading (in your stream) are the slider's images, you can also speed this up by optimising your images. In revolution slider's settings you can also change the pre-loading behaviour & icon (which is likely white as well hence the 'square').

Hope this helps you somewhat.